# How to prevent upload the file on submit the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I uploading the file in django with progress bar, and when i choose the file the progress start and when the finish that's mean the file uploaded but when I click in submit form the file upload again and this mean the progress bar is useless, so I want to make something like when I click in submit button the file save with the form but not upload again how I can do this?

my form

```
class Video_form(forms.ModelForm,):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ('video', 'video_poster', 'title',)
```

the view

```
def VideosUploadView(request, *args, **kwargs):
V_form = Video_form()
video_added = False

if not request.user.is_active:
    # any error you want
    return render('account/login.html')

try:
    account = Account.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
except:
    # any error you want
    return HttpResponse('User does not exits.')

if 'submit_v_form' in request.POST:
    print(request.POST)
    V_form = Video_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if V_form.is_valid():
        instance = V_form.save(commit=False)

        video = request.FILES['video']
        clip = VideoFileClip(video.temporary_file_path())
        instance.video_duration = clip.duration

        instance.author = account
        instance.save()
        V_form.save_m2m()
        V_form = Video_form()
        video_added = True

        if instance.save:
            return redirect('home')
contex = {
    'account': account,
    'V_form': V_form,
    'video_added': video_added,
}


return render(request, "video/upload_videos.html", contex)
```

the template

```
<form  id="upload-form" action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div id="progress-box" class="d-none">progress</div>

                                <div class="custom-file">

                                     <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="formGroupExampleInput2" required value="{{V_form.video}}">
                                     <label class="custom-file-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">Choose Video...</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="custom-file mt-5 mb-4">

                                       <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file2" required value="{{V_form.video_poster}}">
                                     <label class="custom-file-label" for="formGroupExampleInput2">Choose Poster For Your Video...</label>

                                </div>

                                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center my-3 px-3" >  <button class="btn-block btnn-color" name="submit_v_form"> Upload</button></div>
                          </form>
```

Comment: what do you mean with ( the file upload again ) ?..does it go to your media folder twice ??

Comment: No, I made uploading files with progress bar, when I choose any file the progress bar start and the file uploaded but I did.'t submit form yet that's meant the file didn't saved yet so when I submit form the file upload again

Comment: can you add some pics to your post ( before and after choosing a  file)